Script freezes when pytorch lightning's Trainer is instantiated
I'm trying to train a model using pytorch lightning in a cluster with Ubuntu 20.04. However, the code freezes once when the lightning.Trainer is instantiated. There are no error messages, it just freezes, the program does not stop. It does not get to output the info regarding available GPU, TPU etc.
This happens to me with different codes, such as the "lightning in 15 minutes" example or even with the following minimal example:
import lightning as L

print("Before instantiate Trainer")
trainer = L.Trainer()
print("After instantiate Trainer")

It simply does not get to the second print. I have tried with different versions of torch and lightning, and happens the same in all of them.
Does anybody know what is going on? Thanks in advance.
UPDATE: I put some prints inside the lightning.Trainer init and I found that it gets stuck just in the line self._accelerator_connector = _AcceleratorConnector.

I managed to overcome the issue by creating a virtual environment with python 3.10 and reinstalling lightning and pytorch there, it worked fine then.
